Mac cmd + tab doesn't work with external keyboard, but cmd works and tab works
Scenario:

External keyboard (cherry keys mx2.0s wireless, if it matters)
Plugged into macbook
Mapping changed in system preferences, so "alt" (right next to space) is mapped to "cmd"
This was working normally a day ago

Testing with on-screen keyboard open so I can see every input:

Alt key successfully triggers the command key as input.
Tab works fine too.
Holding command ("alt" on the keyboard) registers as command but hitting tab while holding command does NOT register.

Troubleshooting:

Relaunched finder
Rebooted
Keyboard off/on
Plugged in keyboard via USB
Cmd + tab works fine on macbook keyboard
Keys work independently. Only when holding alt(cmd), the tab key doesn't seem to register, but on its own it works...
Cmd + ` works fine to change windows in current app

So weird, does anyone have any troubleshooting ideas?

So, with cherry keys, on the F9 key there's a "win lk" label. Hit FN + "win lk" and it switches mode on the keyboard. Suddenly cmd tab works again and the option key also works again (win key).
